# Intel Compiler 18.0 Toolset raises exception with msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, icc

I reinstalled my machine and installed `Visual Studio 2017`, `Visual Studio 2019 (Preview)` and the `Intel Compiler 18`. Due to unknown reasons, my projects do not work anymore, and I can't figure out what's causing it. Did anyone ever experience the following error message?

My project uses the `Intel C++ Compiler 18.0` toolset.

**Visual Studio 2017 error message**:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xmemory0(178):
error : identifier "__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__" is undefined
1>      enable_if_t<(!_HAS_ALIGNED_NEW || _Align <=
__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__), int> = 0> inline
```

**Visual Studio 2019 (Preview) error message**:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\Intel C++ Compiler 18.0\Toolset.targets(150,5):
error MSB4062: The "ICMessage" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Intel.Build.ICLTasks.v150.dll.
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Intel.Build.ICLTasks.v150.dll' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.
Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

Before the reinstallation, my project worked fine. Does anyone have an idea what's going on here?

Comment: Hi Daniel, is there any update for the original issue `identifier "__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__" is undefined`? If you're resolved it, you can consider sharing the useful info here, which may help members with similar issue !

Comment: Yes, besides the given answer here, this also solved my issue: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279256/intel-compiler-uses-wrong-header/58317776?noredirect=1#comment103023924_58317776` ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The system cannot find the file specified.

1.Check whether the `Intel.Build.ICLTasks.v150.dll` exists in the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\xxx\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets`. According to the error message it's not there, so i guess the Intel Compiler 18 was not successfully installed.

Note that `recommended order` to do the installation is: Install VS successfully and then install Intel Compiler. If you install the Intel Compiler before installing the VS2017, it will cause issues.

**e.g:** After installing VS, when I install the Intel Parallel Studio, it will download several files and assemblies to folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets` for future development. So if I install Intel compiler before installing VS, I can't find `Intel.Build.ICLTasks.v150.dll` there.

2.And for your original error message in VS2017, I suggest you update your Intel Compiler to `2019 Update3` and higher, see [versions](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-compilers-integration-support-for-microsoft-visual-studio-2017). When you reinstall VS, the installer will download latest 15.9.16 version(newer than your old version), so you also need to upgrade your Intel compiler version to resolve some conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried my luck but gave up halfway on VS2019. I try to uninstall and reinstall everything now.

Comment: @DanielStephens Hi, any update for this issue? What's the specific Intel Compiler 18 version in your machine?  For VS15.9.16, I suggest you should install 19 with Update3 and higher... :)

Comment: @DanielStephens I found several similar issues like this one, and there's high possibility that this issue results from the Incompatibility between VS and Parallel Studio version. See [one](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/784700), [two](https://software.intel.com/pt-br/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/779223), [three](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/316602/intel-c-fails-to-compile-type-traits.html)... I guess why your project won't work after the reinstall is because VS will automatically update to latest version when someone install it.

Comment: Then this behavior broke the relationship described in [this document]()https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-compilers-integration-support-for-microsoft-visual-studio-2017, the Intel Compiler version is too old for VS version, cause the unknown issues about Incompatibility. Hope it can help resolve your puzzle !