# Intel Compiler uses wrong header

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, icc, intel-composer

I am trying to find out why the `Intel Compiler 18.0`, which got installed **after** my Visual Studio 2017 installation, uses the header files of `MSVC`, instead of it's own one (since it results in errors).

A simple `#include <vector>` triggers this error in an otherwise empty translation unit when compiled in a C++ project within Visual Studio

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\type_traits(1562): error : expected a ">"
1>      _INLINE_VAR constexpr bool _Is_specialization_v<_Template<_Types...>, _Template> = true;
```

Just to be sure, why is it using the `MSVC` includes anyway? A reinstallation did not result in any change. I simply can't figure out, why it's causing this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> About the error message you got:

I think you're experiencing the same issue like [this one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/316602/intel-c-fails-to-compile-type-traits.html), in most time this issue is caused by the **incompatibility** between `Intel Parallel Studio XE version` and `VS version`. Just like what I suggested in your [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58253760/intel-compiler-18-0-toolset-raises-exception-with-msbuild), you need to install the higher version of Intel Parallel Studio XE version to resolve the issue.

> Just to be sure, why is it using the MSVC includes anyway? A
>   reinstallation did not result in any change. I simply can't figure
>   out, why it's causing this problem. Any ideas?

Intel C++ Compiler works an extension for VS. You can check it in `Tools=>Extensions and Updates`:

[image]

Agree with **Adrian**'s `I don't think Intel would want to 'take ownership' of MFC`. For a simple C++ project, if we set Intel C++ compiler as its compiler, what would exactly happen behind? Let's see the project file(xx.vcxproj):

It sets the `<PlatformToolset>Intel C++ Compiler 19.0</PlatformToolset>`, and may do some other changes to the `xx.vcxproj`, but that project still have definitions like `<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />`,   `<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />` in its project file.

So some peroperties, definitions about MSVC will still be imported during build process. That's why the error message you got contains `MSVC`...

**Note:**

1. [MSbuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019) is the build engine of VS, it reads the content of `xx.vcxproj` to compile and build the project.
2. There're many tasks, properties, Items for normal C++ build process are defined in imported targets files like `Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props`,`$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets` and so on.
3. When we `right-click project=>Intel Compiler=>Use Intel C++` , it changed the platformToolSet setting, but it still import the xx.cpp.targets as part of build process. So you can see error message about MSVC or what in build output.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to know it makes some help:)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to turn off "Conformance Mode" (`/permissive-`) for configurations that use the Intel compiler! (This mode forces stricter adherence to standards, which Intel C++ can't handle when using the MSVC implementation of the STL.)

Right-click project: Properties -> C/C++ -> Language then select "No" for Conformance Mode.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try, I am just wondering though why it uses these headers at all. Shouldn’t it use its own ones?

Comment: I think the point is that Intel C++ tries to be 'completely' compatible with Visual Studio and/or MSVC. For example, when building MFC apps - I don't think Intel would want to 'take ownership' of MFC, or that Microsoft would even let them.

Comment: I agree, but a plain C++ project, before it used its own headers. I can’t switch simply now to different ones. Hm